# writing hmac_sha1 algorithm in python

Tags: python, algorithm, hmacsha1

in python programming scope, i have tried to write the hmac-sha1 function in python.
the code is shown below. But the value returned seems not to be the correct value.

computed hmac : cb1e45d7fb852695e63731edb4f58547f9249ad9

value must be : de7c9b85b8b78aa6bc8a7a36f70a90701c9db4d9

is there any error in my code and how to fix it up to get the expected value.

thanks

```
#HMAC

import hashlib


toHex = lambda x:"".join([hex(ord(c))[2:].zfill(2) for c in x])  #return string

# initiate i_pad and o_pad
i_pad = int('36'*64,16)
o_pad = int('5C'*64,16)

def hmac(key,msg):
    print('key=',key,'msg=',msg)
    h_key = toHex(key)
    h_msg = int(toHex(msg),16)

    if len(h_key)>128:
        #hash key if len(key) > 64 bytes
        h_key = hashlib.sha1(h_key.encode('ascii'))
    while len(h_key)<128:
        # padding key to 64 bytes
        h_key+='00'

    h_key = (int(h_key,16))                  
    i_key_pad = h_key ^ i_pad
    o_key_pad = h_key ^ o_pad

    #first pass
    first_msg=hex(i_key_pad)[2:] + hex(h_msg)[2:]    
    hash1 = hashlib.sha1(first_msg.encode('ascii'))         
    #second pass
    second_msg = hex(o_key_pad)[2:] + hash1.hexdigest()
    hash2 = hashlib.sha1(second_msg.encode('ascii'))  
    return hash2.hexdigest()


def test():
    hash = hmac("key", "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")
    print('computed hmac',hash)
    print('value must be de7c9b85b8b78aa6bc8a7a36f70a90701c9db4d9')

test1()
```

Comment: You seem to be operating with the hexadecimal representation of the key and the message, while bytes are expected.

Comment: but I have to go hex for key to be able to xor with i_pad and o_pad which are hex strings by definition ! can't xor bytes with bytes ! but when i use sha1(), I convert to bytes ! BTW does msg have to stay raw (non hex) before sha1 ?

Comment: By [definition of HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC#Implementation) all of o_pad, i_pad, key and message are bytes. You only need to convert them to hex to print them nicely.

Comment: Probably a silly question, but do you have to implement the HMAC-SHA1 algorithm yourself -- that is, this is school work -- or would it be acceptable to just let the standard library do it? If so, then if you import [hmac](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/hmac.html) and [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/hashlib.html), then  `hmac.new(b"key", b"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog",hashlib.sha1).digest().hex()` does the trick.

Comment: i just try to implement the algorithm myself for practice and to verify result by myself. sure it is better to let standard library do the work when it's all you need but i still need to put my hands in the gears to see how it turns!

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten my code for bytes but the result is still incorrect !

```
from hashlib import sha1
import sys

def encrypt1(var, key):
    return bytes(a ^ b for a, b in zip(var, key))

#The second one uses int.from_bytes and int.to_bytes: 20 x faster
def encrypt2(var, key):
    key = key[:len(var)]
    int_var = int.from_bytes(var, sys.byteorder)
    int_key = int.from_bytes(key, sys.byteorder)
    int_enc = int_var ^ int_key
    return int_enc.to_bytes(len(var), sys.byteorder)

key, msg = b'key', b'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
# initiate i_pad and o_pad
i_pad = b'6'*64   # chr(0x36)='6'
o_pad = b'\\'*64   # chr(0x5C)='\\'
print(i_pad)
print(o_pad)

key = key+b'0'*(64-len(key))
print(key,len(key))

i_key_pad = encrypt2(i_pad, key)
print(i_key_pad)

o_key_pad = encrypt2(o_pad, key)
print(o_key_pad)

#first pass
first_msg = i_key_pad + msg
print(first_msg, len(first_msg))
hash1 = sha1(first_msg)
#print(hash1.hexdigest())
print(hash1.digest())

#second pass
second_msg = o_key_pad + hash1.digest()
print(second_msg, len(second_msg))
hash2 = sha1(second_msg)
print(hash2.hexdigest())

print('de7c9b85b8b78aa6bc8a7a36f70a90701c9db4d9 expected')`
```

Comment: Solve my problem : key = key+b'\0'*(64-len(key))


I complemented with '0' and not '\0' !!!!!

Comment: I've changed `b'6'*64` to `b'0'*64`. Shouldn't `print(hash2.hexdigest())` give me `de7c9b85b8b78aa6bc8a7a36f70a90701c9db4d9`? I'm getting `e705586e6a0e428456d0643e3f657652a7b06e5a`. With `b'6'*64` I'm getting `239996c560044779ba29a6b550e5c17efeb716c0`

Comment: I misread Jeans comment. As he said `key = key+b'0'*(64-len(key))` needs to be changed to `key = key+b'\0'*(64-len(key))`